# How to fix this CSS 3 code to make it working properly on the server?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, stylesheet

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am struggling right now with the following issue; I have CSS3 code, for adding shadow to each Div in my code, that is working fine with me on my machine. I have Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 9 and everything is working fine.

Now, after moving my code to the server that is still running Window Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5. The CSS3 code is not reflecting or displaying as on my machine and I don't know why. What is causing this? Also, **could you please tell me how I can fix the following CSS3 (if possible) to make it displaying properly when I transfer it to the server?**

*CSS 3 Code:*

```
.shadow
{
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px black;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px #888;
}
```

Comment: maybe some real example?  How do you expect we help you? no comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your document is appearing in Quirks Mode when being served from the server. When Internet Explorer renders a document in Quirks Mode, it no longer supports many modern features like box-shadows and border-radius.

To ensure that your document appears in Standards Mode, which supports the latest features of the browser you're using, be sure to use a standards doctype, such as the short HTML5 doctype:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This should be the very first line in your HTML.

You can verify the Document Mode by pressing F12 and accessing your Developer Tools. Located at the top of these tools will be your present Document Mode: this will inform you as to whether you're in Standards Mode, or Quirks Mode. You can change it here as well to test the difference on your document.